# .htaccess redirect not working for pdf files

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've changed the .htacces for a website to redirect every request to a new site, except for anything begining with `wp` (wp-admin, wp-content, etc).

I've added the below code which works fine for all pages, but not for PDF files (which are stored in `/wp-content/`).  These don't get redirected to the new site, but just open normally.  The second `RewriteCond` should also pick up any PDF files and redirect them but it isn't working.  Even if I change the URL of the PDF file to a made up one, I go through to the 404 page of the old site and not redirected to the new site.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/products?utm_medium=$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have put the code through a couple of different .htaccess testing tools and they both say it should work perfectly.  I've extensively tried different options and different flags, including splitting the mod_rewrites into separate blocks, nothing makes the pdf files redirect.

I've read through the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html and can't find any reason why this doesn't work.

Below is a copy of the entire .htaccess file for reference.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp.*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/products?utm_medium=$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /wp/example-product-1/ https://www.example.com/products/example-product-1/
Redirect 301 /wp/example-product-2/ https://www.example.com/products/example-product-2/
Redirect 301 /wp/example-product-3/ https://www.example.com/products/example-product-3/

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Would welcome any comments or suggestions, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that you are simply looking at client side cached documents when you test?

Comment: I've tested it in private browsers and I've also tested it by making up random PDF names with ".pdf" after it.  Real links still open the file, and random links with .pdf after it go through to the 404 page on the original website (don't get redirected to new website)

Comment: Is there any way the rule could be overridden in a subfolder?  I've put the [L] flags on the rules to try and prevent this.

Comment: Sure you can override that in a subfolder. Which is one of the reasons why using such distributed configuration files (".htaccess") might not be such a good idea in the end, because things can get really complicated and nearly impossible to debug. Keeping such rules in a _central_ configuration is much less complex. The `L` flag won't help much with that. You'd need to use the `END` flag instead.